# Cannot install Spark IM 2.6.3, getting permission denied error even though I am root

Tags: installation, permissions, sudo

I am trying to install [Spark IM](http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp) in my Ubuntun VM, however I am running into all kinds of problems. The steps I have taken so far were:

1. Download the tar.gz file from the website
2. Unpack it
3. `cd /home/user/Downloads/Spark`
4. `sudo chmod +x Spark`
5. `sudo chmod +x starter`
6. `cd ..`
7. `sudo mv Spark/ /opt`

To run, the Spark IM, I do the following commands:

1. `sudo su`
2. `cd /opt`
3. `sh Spark/Spark`

And as a result, I get the error:

```
Preparing JRE ...
Spark/Spark: 150: Spark/Spark: bin/unpack200: Permission denied
Error unpacking jar files. Aborting.
You might need administrative priviledges for this operation.
```

Which makes no sense at all, because I am running in root mode. If I run `sh Spark/starter` I get the exact same mistake. If I try to run it as an executable file, I get a similar error:

```
bash: ./Spark/starter: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can I not install this?

Comment: Hmm.. What's the output of `ls -Al` in `/opt/Shark`?

Comment: You mean `la -Al /opt/Spark`? Well the output ca be seen here: http://pastebin.kde.org/py1ldorue

I wonder if it is somehow related to my versions of Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting permission denied is because the files `Spark` and `starter` don't have execute permissions as seen here:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 8528 Jan 20 19:38 Spark
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 7520 Jan 20 19:38 starter
```

So you will need to run:

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/Spark  
sudo chmod +x /opt/starter
```

I'm not sure why the execute permission was lost (since you ran `chmod +x` before), but I think it is because when you moved them to `/opt` the owner was changed from you to root.